# Maximum Concurrency when using QUIC protocol

Tags: chrome

I am using QUIC to make some internal performance test.
  However when I review the result I found Chrome loaded the page very similar with HTTP, restricting by the maximum concurrency(for chrome , it is 6).
   I have thought that when Chrome loaded a page through QUIC, it actually works on SPDY(quic+spdy). It should not limited by the maximum concurrency.

My env :

- OS : ubuntu 1404, 64bit
- Chrome : 39.0,
- start option : chrome --incognito --enable-quic --origin-to-force-quic-on=test.site:80 http://test.site/
- 100ms latency between client and server

Here is the screen capture :

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: What are you using to provide a QUIC server?

Comment: I just used the quic server google provide, refer here : http://www.chromium.org/quic/playing-with-quic